# Unknown Error : insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Tags: c#, sqlite

in C# project , I have made a datagridview in my form that has some columns.column[0]& column[1] names are fix (day and date) and the other column names are variable and will change by user.these columns have time period thatsis shown with starting and finishing time.
such as from 6 am to 14 pm is shown as 6_14 as columns name.we have a listbox that has variable number of items(counter "i").

```
///sqlite doesn't accept columns name that start and finish with Numbers.I added word "f" to start and end of each
///column name

string data_str = "";
string data_str2="";

for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count;i++ )
{
    string temp = "f"+ listBox1.Items[i].ToString()+"f";
    data_str = data_str + temp +",";

    string temp2 =  "@"+listBox1.Items[i].ToString()+",";
    data_str2=data_str2+temp2;
}

data_str=data_str.TrimEnd(',');
data_str2=data_str2.TrimEnd(',');
```

in first step,I made two columns "day" & "date" in data table in my database and imported my data to it successfully.(It works)

```
string Q_insert = "insert into " + table_name + " (day,date) values (@day,@date)";
SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(connection_string);
SQLiteCommand insert_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Q_insert, connect);
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in shift_datagrid.Rows)
{

    insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim());
    insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim());

    connect.Open();
    insert_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connect.Close();
}
```

in second step,I need to import user data from datagridview to data table but the error takes place.(it doesn't work)

```
int col_cnt = listBox1.Items.Count;

Q_insert = "insert into " + table_name + " (" + data_str + ") values (" + data_str2 + ")";
connect = new SQLiteConnection(connection_string);
insert_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Q_insert, connect);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in shift_datagrid.Rows)
{

    string temp1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < col_cnt; i++)
    {           
        temp1 = "\"@" + listBox1.Items[i].ToString() +"\"";
        insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(temp1, row.Cells[i + 2].Value.ToString().Trim()); 
    }

    connect.Open();
    insert_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connect.Close();       
}
```

unfortunately, this error occurs:
unknown Error : `Insufficient parameters supplied to the command`
I googled this error and checked solution ways for same problems but they were not useful for my problem and they couldn't help me anyway.

this is the example of output command strings that insert to data to database (two steps):
**1.** Insert into [table_name] (day,date) values (@day,@date) -------------->(it works)
**2.** Insert into [table_name] (f6_14f,f14_22f,f22_6f) values (@6_14,@14_22,@22_6) ------->(it doesn't work)

please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following may be causing the error:

```
temp1 = "\"@" + listBox1.Items[i].ToString() +"\"";
insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(temp1, row.Cells[i + 2].Value.ToString().Trim());
```

Syntax requires that you don't construct the @ as part of the variable value.@ is not data. Use it as part of the variable name as you did before like this:

```
insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1",listBox1.Items[i+2].Value.ToString().Trim());
```

Where @Col1 is a column name of your table.

I don't think you can build the parameter name in a for loop, if so, you have to list the insert statements with each column name parameter prefixed with @ as in the above example/code.

Comment: Hi.again..you're right.I cant use this command format.but ,in your idea, How I can define variable parameters to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that. However, if you don't want to specify the parameters manually, you could consider the CommandBuilder approach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That is good, I thought you were asking about a way to generate parameter names...

Comment: i cant find any solution then i had to do this